# Fullcalendar falsely renders event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am implementing fullcalendar on my webpage and I have encountered weird bug. Event has everything set correctly, but when the calendar is loaded it is displayed on a wrong spot in the calendar and with wrong duration. When I drag the event or refresh the calendar, the event is placed correctly and its duration too. Even the time stamp in the event title is correct, just the position is wrong. The problem also only occurs, when there is only one event in the calendar, with multiple events, everything is right.

```
_render: function(){
    this._super('_render',arguments);
    this.getCalendar().fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable:true,
        height: 600,

    });
    this.getCalendar().fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', {
        title: "purple",
        start: "2018-02-07T11:30:00+01:00",
        end: "2018-02-07T14:15:00+01:00",
        color: "purple",
    }, true);
    // this.renderMeetings();
},
```

[image: How it looks like, when the calendar is loaded]
[image: How it looks like, when I drag the event a little (or reload the calendar events) - this is correct time and duration of the event]

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Also notice the grey areas of "non-working" hours are misplaced

EDIT: Narrowed the problem a little bit - it occurs even when I simply try to render static event

EDIT2: simplified calendars setting, still the same...

EDIT3: when I tried the code on a blank page, it worked as expected, so the calendar must somehow interfere with my other code... any ideas how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if the "official" method to add new events to the calendar is through the renderEvent method. As the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/) states, it can cause your events to dissapear when paging.

Try adding your events with the [addEventSource](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) method, something like this:

```
renderMeetings: function(){
    this.getCalendar().fullCalendar( 'removeEvents');
    var dates = this.getCalendarDateRange();
    var userId = this.controls.get('userId') || app.user.id;
    var meetings = app.data.createRelatedCollection(app.data.createBean('Users',{id:userId}), 'meetings');
    var start = moment(dates.start.toISOString()).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    var end = moment(dates.end.toISOString()).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    meetings.fetch({
        filter: {
            "date_start" : {"$between" : [start,end]},
        },
        success: _.bind(function(){
            this.getCalendar().fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', 
                meetings.map(function(meeting){
                    return {
                        title:meeting.get('name'),
                        start: meeting.get('date_start'),
                        end: meeting.get('date_end'),
                        color: meeting.get('name'),
                        id: meeting.id,
                        module: meeting.module
                    }
                },this));
        },this),
        limit: -1
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, but not a fix, so I won't mark it as an answer...

When i call `this.getCalendar().fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' )` after the event is rendered, the event is placed correctly.